# Basic Soap Request issue

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I am very new to SOAP protocol.

I have this sample SOAP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <processSOAPReq xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <sRequest>string</sRequest>
      <sResponse>string</sResponse>
    </processSOAPReq>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am given another xml with sample request. I have been trying to put this sample request inside the  `<sRequest>string</sRequest>` above but I always get `Bad Request` or

```
server was unable to process request. ---> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: input
```

What am I doing wrong. I have been trying for a long time now using SOAPUI.

Btw I also have wsdl but I still do not understand what the correct request should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you check if the values are matching the parameters, and double check the wsdl file.

Comment: Does the wsdl file tell me the exact request that I should be making?

Comment: SOAP UI generates a request based on the wsdl. So you can use that request template.

Comment: This helped me and i double checked the wsdl file. I found out that I have to pass a whole xml as a string. Quite stupid and nonintuitive in my opinion but thats how they wrote the webservice.